# Нужна помощь в js каррирование

Tags: javascript

Всем привет,помогите пожалуйста,Как написать универсальную функцию для любого типа приветствия и передать этой функции имя человека, которого мы хотим поприветствовать.И при этом создать две частичных функции с шаблонами “Hello, {Name}!” и “Hi! I’m {Name}.” И это надо сделать через каррирование)

```
 var userName = 'Вася';

    function showMessage() {
      userName = 'Петя'; 

      var message = 'Привет, я ' + userName;
      alert( message );
    }
showMessage();
Что то типо такого,только через каррирование
```

Comment: Приведи примеры этих функций. Сейчас непонятно что они должны принимать и что возвращать

Answer (score 1):

Не вполне понятно чего вы хотите, но допустим так:

```js
function hi(name) {
  return function(greet) {
    return `${greet}, ${name}`;
  };
}

console.log(hi('Alex')('Hi'))
```

---

Немного ближе к тексту вопроса:

```js
const hi = name => tpl => tpl.replace(/{Name}/g, name);

console.log(hi('Alex')('Hi, {Name}'))
console.log(hi('Alex')('Привет, я {Name}.'))
```

Comment: чем второй блок ближе к тексту?

Comment: Наличием темплейта